# Power Query in Excel and pattern recognition

Tags: powerquery

As Power Query does not provide support for RegEx how can I extract a number of 8 digits from a string.

The number can appear anywhere in the string.

I have tried to use M but didn't find any complete solution. I also tried the option "Column From Examples" but the complexity of the cases does not let me have a reliable result either.

I googled it but it seems there are no examples suitable for PowerQuery/M

abc123456 -->null

abc12345678 -->12345678

abc 12345678 -->12345678

abc 12345678aaaa -->12345678

abc 1111 ddd12345678aaaa 3467-->12345678

abc 1111 ddd123456aaaa 3467-->null

etc...

**EDIT**

I have added the following code as suggested by Alexis Olson

```
= Table.AddColumn(
    Sheet1_Sheet,
    "PatternMatched",
    (r) =>
        List.First(
            List.Select(
                List.Transform(
                    {0..Text.Length(r[String]) - 8},
                    each Text.Range(r[String], _, 8)
                ),
                each _ = Text.Select(_, {"0".."9"})
            )
        )
)
```

the code differs only for `Sheet1_Sheet` instead of `#"Previous Step"` because this is the field holding the data but I get the following error message *"Expression.Error: The field 'String' of the record wasn't found. Details: Column1=abc123456"* What am I doing wrong ?

**EDIT2**

I have found the error in my formula. Here the correct one

```
Table.AddColumn(
    #"Renamed Columns",
    "PatternMatched",
    (r) =>
        List.First(
            List.Select(
                List.Transform(
                    {0..Text.Length(r[Column]) - 8},
                    each Text.Range(r[Column], _, 8)
                ),
                each _ = Text.Select(_, {"0".."9"})
            )
        )
)
```

I had simply to replace from Alexis Olson's answer:

- `#"Previous Step"` with `#"Renamed Columns"` because that is the previous step name in the **"Applied Steps"** section of the **"Query Settings"** in PQ
- `r[String]` with `r[Column]` because "Column" is the name of the
  column containing the data I want to find the pattern in my PQ

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not simple, but you could add a custom column that does this:

```
Table.AddColumn(
    #"Previous Step",
    "PatternMatched",
    (r) =>
        List.First(
            List.Select(
                List.Transform(
                    {0..Text.Length(r[String]) - 8},
                    each Text.Range(r[String], _, 8)
                ),
                each _ = Text.Select(_, {"0".."9"})
            )
        )
)
```

Let's take a look at what's happening here with the example `r[String] = abc12345678`.

1. Since `Text.Length(r[String]) = 11`, we can look at substring ranges of length 8 starting at index `0` through index `11 - 8 = 3`.
2. So `List.Transform({0,1,2,3}, each Text.Range("abc12345678", _, 8))` transforms the list `{0,1,2,3}` into a list of 8-long substring ranges: `{"abc12345", "bc123456", "c1234567", "12345678"}`.
3. Now for each of these substrings, check if it consists of only digits by comparing each string to a version of itself containing only digits using `Text.Select(_,  {"0".."9"})` to strip all but the digit characters. Then `List.Select` each substring where this condition is true.
4. The result is a list of substrings that are a length of 8 and contain only digits (empty if none exist). Use `List.First` to return the first string from this list.

[image: Result Screenshot]

Comment: I have made a slight adjustment to your code in order to adapt it my sheet but now I have an error message. I have edited my original question with my code.

Comment: I have found the mistake in my formula and added a further edit with the explanation of the solution.